# Highlighting Non-Consecutive Duplicates in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to show duplicates for a column in google sheets. I can show all duplicates using =countif(B:B,B:B)>1. In this case though, I only want it to highlight them if they are NOT consecutive. For example, if I have:
A
B
B
B
C
D
E
F
B

I would like for only the final 'B' to be highlighted.

The closest code I could find was this: =MATCH(2,1/(A$2:A$13=A2))-MATCH(A2,A$2:A$13,0)<>COUNTIF(A$2:A$13,A2)-1
and it didn't work - it highlights the very first B of the three consecutive ones, and does not highlight non-consecutive ones at all. It has to be only the bottom, non-consecutive one because when someone adds something to the column, they're adding it to the bottom, and they need to know they're adding something that's already there.

I only know python and SQL, I haven't messed with google sheets much before. In Python-ish terms, the logic I'm trying to use is:

B(i or j) = arbitrary cell in column B
IF B(i) EXACTLY EQUALS B(j), AND B(i) DOES NOT EQUAL (B(i-1) OR B(i+1)), color = red

I just don't know how to translate that logic to a google sheets conditional format.

Any ideas??
TIA for any help!

Comment: So if it was `ABBCCCDDB` you would still only want `B`?

Comment: @pgSystemTester Yes, so these are basically tracking IDs of shipments, if one is repeated consecutively it's because there is an issue with a container on that ID and we need to add lines to write in the issues. We can't highlight the consecutive ones red because there is a column next to it that highlights red to mean DO NOT SHIP that container, so it would confuse people (since there are dozens of people looking at the sheet, which is why IDs keep getting added twice).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the range starts in A1, you can use the following conditional formatting custom formula:

```cpp
=AND(A1<>"",COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,AND(IFERROR(OFFSET(A1,-1,0)<>A1,0),OFFSET(A1,1,0)<>A1))
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks so much. This has been causing problems all the time at work, I'm so glad it's finally fixed.